# one sub menu changed colour but the rest correct

Tags: css

I am having a problem with one sub-menu. Instead of picking up the colour from the main menu (1) at the top, it takes its colour from the next main menu (2). It is third in the list of sub-menus, and if I add a forth then that one takes its colour from the following main menu (3). And yet I have sub-menus from main menus 2 and 3 that work just fine.

```
#header ul {
    margin:auto;
    padding: 1px; 
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
}
#header ul li {
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
   padding:0;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   top:1px;
}
#header  ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #069;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Any ideas?

```
#header ul li:first-child a {
    color:#F60;
}
#header  ul li:nth-child(2) a{
    color:#099;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(3) a{
    color:#C0C;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(4) a{
    color:#09F;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(5) a{
    color:#F60;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(6) a{
    color:#e0b51e;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(7) a{
    color:#F0F;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(8) a{
    color:#93C;
}
#header ul li:nth-child(9) a{
    color:#690;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
    color:#00C;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:#dff4f3; /* Top menu items background colour */
}  
#header ul li:hover a,
#header ul li.hover a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   background:#dff4f3; /* Top menu items background colour */
}   
/* Submenu items */
#header ul ul {
   display:none; /* Sub menus are hiden by default */
   position:absolute;
   top:2em;
   left:0;
   right:auto; /*resets the right:50% on the parent ul */
   width:13em; /* width of the drop-down menus */
}
#header ul ul li {
   left:auto;  /*resets the left:50% on the parent li */
   margin:0; /* Reset the 1px margin from the top menu */
   clear:left;
   width:100%;
}
#header ul ul li a,
#header ul li.active li a,
#header ul li:hover ul li a,
#header ul li.hover ul li a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   font-size:.9em;
   font-weight:normal; /* resets the bold set for the top level menu items */
   background:#dff4f3;
   border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; /* sub menu item horizontal lines */
}
#header ul ul li a:hover,
#header ul li.active ul li a:hover,
#header ul li:hover ul li a:hover,
#header ul li.hover ul li a:hover { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   background:#dff4f3; /* Sub menu items background colour */
   color:#00C;
}

/* Flip the last submenu so it stays within the page */
#header ul ul.last {
   left:auto; /* reset left:0; value */
   right:0; /* Set right value instead */
}

/* Make the sub menus appear on hover */
#header ul li:hover ul,
#header ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   display:block; /* Show the sub menus */
}
```

and the html is

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="history.html">History of the Charity</a></li>
            <li><a href="funding.html">Funding</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Do you need help?</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="help.html#sup-gardening">Supported Gardening</a></li>
            <li><a href="new-beginnings.html">New Beginnings</a></li>
            <li><a href="jobdone.html">Job Done Project</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="support-services2col.html">Support Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="support-nhs.html">Health Practitioners</a></li>
            <li><a href="support-schools.html">Educational Practitioners</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="vol2col.html">Volunteers</a></li>
        <li><a href="timetable.html">Timetable</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PtmBm/)**

The problem was here:

```
#header ul li:nth-child(3) a{
    color:#C0C;
}
```

The above CSS rule changes color to *#C0C* in **every third** `li` of **every** `ul` in `#header`.

You had to be more specific with selectors and separate them with `>` sign like this

```
#header > ul > li:nth-child(3) a{
```

`>` is a `immediate child` selector. The difference is when you type

```
ul#menu li
```

it will match all `li`'s within `ul` even those nested deeper, like

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> //this will obviously match the CSS rule
        <ul>
            <li></li> //this will also match!
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but when you type

```
ul#menu > li
```

only **immediate** `li` children of `ul` will match:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> //only this will match
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You star!! Works perfectly.